# How do I get to the northwestern terminal?

Tags: 1000-amps

Here's the map:

[image]

It looks like the two circled areas are the only two ways up to the unexplored areas, going through the unsolved room to the right and then teleporting along to the left to the other unsolved rooms.. One is a long, dark vertical shaft with no-teleport marks, so that's the way down. The other way is at the top of this room:

[image]

This room seems *impossible* to climb, requiring split-second reflexes to avoid either falling off the elevator or being caught in the current and pushed down into the room below. My experience has been that rooms that seem to require impossible reflexes actually have a simpler solution. I'm stumped, though, and as you can see it's the only terminal I haven't yet reached.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to ride the elevator past the currents by not turning the currents on (so everything is still dark), even without the streams the final jump was a little tricky.  You've already powered up the room permanently, so you don't have that option...  The best I can say is stay to the left edge of the elevator, push left as the elevator takes you up into a stream, and have the cursor lined up to teleport over to the platform on the right as soon as it gets into view.

I just tried this approach myself in this room with all the lights on, and its tricky but not out of line with some of the other dexterity puzzles in this game.